# Communicating with ReactJS components in different Meteor packages

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I am building a web application using ReactJS and Meteor.  I am using the method of structuring my application where components are split into separate Meteor packages.

For example. I have a component which renders a tabular menu (using the semantic-ui tab module) and initializes the tabs, then each tab is its own React component.

How would I be able to access the DOM in one component in another component.

Example:

```
Component = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount() {
      $('.menu .item').tab({
        onVisible: () => {
          // I need to call a function here, which is defined in OtherComponent, 
          // but this jQuery won't run in OtherComponent
        }
      })
    },

    render() {
      return (
        <div className="ui tabular menu">
          <div className="active item" data-tab="tab-1">Tab 1</div>
          <div className="item" data-tab="tab-2">Tab 2</div>
        </div>

        /* more code */

        <div className="ui active tab" data-tab="tab-1"></div>
        <div className="ui tab" data-tab="tab-2"></div>
       )
    }
}

OtherComponentInDifferentPackage = React.createClass({
   componentDiMount() {
      $('.menu .item').tab({
        onVisible: () => {
           // this won't work.... 
        }
      })
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to have a parent component that holds state and can pass that as props to both components. In react you can also pass functions as props, in this case you could pass a function from the parent to the children that will trigger a state change in the parent. To change the state of parent you would call `this.props.toggleVisible()` from the child.

```
// Parent Component
toggleVisible() {
  this.setState({
    visible: !this.state.visible
  });
}
getInitialState() {
  return {
    visible: false
  }
}
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Component
        visible={this.state.visible}
        toggleVisible={this.toggleVisible}
      />
      <OtherComponentInDifferentPackage
        visible={this.state.visible}
        toggleVisible={this.toggleVisible}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

// Child Component
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.visible !== this.props.visible) {
    // do something
  }
}
```